# Подсветка края бокового меню (android)

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочеться сделать подсветку края бокового меню, как в EBookDroid. Пожалуйста, подскажите, каким спосом реализован данный эффект?

Comment: И все дружно начали скачивать EbookDroid... Скриншот приложить тяжело?

Comment: Обычный View с градиентом справа от бокового меню через `layout_alignParentRight="true"` и `layout_centerVertical="true"`